# How can I most efficiently work around my editor's limitations to create bidirectional text?

Tags: babel, texshop, bidi, sublime-text

I have used and loved Sublime Text on a Mac for a number of years. Now, however, I need to produce a series of documents with bidirectional text (i.e., both RTL and LTR languages), which ST doesn't appear to support. TexShop *does* support bidirectional text, apparently, but I don't find it comfortable to work with and don't want to spend time learning a new system while also working to a deadline. So my tentative plan is:

1. Compose document in ST, with placeholders where I need to put the RTL text
2. Switch to TexShop to put in the RTL text where needed
3. Switch back to ST to compile.

My question is: **is this the best available workflow for what I'm trying to do, or is there a better way to solve this problem?**

Comment: BabelPad (free app) can do both directions (amongst other things). And RTL works in TeXworks (with TL); I gave it Code2003 as the edit font, so everything is visible.

Comment: If the RTL texts are more or less isolated and its number is small, and option is to create separate files with them and then `\input` the files. Just an idea.